# How to get username in vi/vim editor?

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to get the find the username/fullname of the current user who invoked the vi/vim editor.

```
:autocmd bufnewfile *.sh exe "1," . 10 . "g/AUTHOR :.*/s//AUTHOR : " .getlogin()
```

I tried using getlogin(), getuser(), getpwnam() but nothing worked.

Comment: What platform are you on? or does this need to be cross-platform?

Comment: Instead of trying random function names next time check `:help functions` or `:help function-list` for something that will suit your needs.  In this case there are no functions for this and you should use environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by others, the following worked for me:

```
autocmd Bufwritepre,Filewritepre *.c,*.vim,*.py,*.sh exe "silent 1," . num_header_lines . "g/MODIFIED BY :.*/s/MODIFIED BY :.*/MODIFIED BY : " . $USER
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `$USER` variable:

```
:echo "Your username is" $USER
```

Answer (score 6):

You could always access the shell indirectly `!:whoami`

This works in cygwin... not sure how platform specific it'll be. 
alternate method, using an environment variable: `:echo expand("$USERNAME")` (or `:echo $USERNAME`)